# how to optimise webpage for loadbalancing between on premise and cloud

Tags: html, load-balancing, netscaler

The setup is that the netscaler and website is on premise, however we expect heavy traffic on a few select pages so we are putting those pages into the cloud with autoscaling (including home page).

So the on-premise netscaler will act as a reverse proxy so the cloud pages will appear to be on the same host as the on-premise website. (I have all the URLS changed to absolute urls to the cloud for associated images etc for the cloud pages).

My question is do the pages need to be optimised for size so that the HTML is smaller - as I'm not clear on whether the reverse proxy needs to load the HTML itself from the cloud into on premise and out to the client to re-write the header (the impression I have from the netscaler tech).  So something like a shell page with a frame that is loaded from the cloud? Would this reduce the load on the netscaler?  Would this introduce any delays to the clients?

Comment: The size of the static HTML of a web-page is less important today compared to having all those external `<script>` elements that pull-in ads, auto-playing videos, marketing trackers, telemetry and so on. If you want fast pages then look at Google AMP - and respect your users!

Comment: it is a huge page with a lot of stuff on it, out of my control, the cloud can autoscale to handle it, I'm just trying to reduce how much of it will go through the on-premise netscaler - hopefully just html and not all the javascript etc?